# ProgressDialog problem during Activiy onCreate():void in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

**Solution:**

Okay,I've found the solution from your answers since your answers are not completely working

First we need to use `Handler` to post a `Runnable` to main/UI thread to run `UpdateDisplay()` and but define `ProgressDialog` under UIThread not other threads which was also crucial.

Here is the final code :

```
public final String RSSFEEDOFCHOICE = "http://www.deals2buy.com/rssgen/tech.xml";

public final String tag = "RSSReader";
private RSSFeed feed = null;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private ProgressDialog dialog;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(RSSReader.this, "Loading",
            "Loading, please wait..");
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            feed = getFeed(RSSFEEDOFCHOICE);
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    UpdateDisplay();
                };
            });
        }
    };

    t.start();
}
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**Problem :**

When Android application first load, this is what happens :

1. Retrieving RSS content from Url and parse it into `RSSFeed feed` instance variable via `getFeed(String url)`.
2. Showing these feeds to users in ListView via `UpdateDisplay()` method.

When these are happening, I wanted to show a ProgressDialog to users to notify them about system are retriving content like "Loading, please wait..." Once `getFeed(String Url):RSSFeed` is done, ProgressDialog will be dismissed and `UpdateDisplay():void` will be invoked.

**So this is my first attempt :**

```
public final String RSSFEEDOFCHOICE = "somewhere.xml"; //coming from http
public final String tag = "RSSReader";
private RSSFeed feed = null;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(RSSReader.this, "Loading...", "Loading, please wait");
    feed = getFeed(RSSFEEDOFCHOICE);
    dialog.dismiss();
    UpdateDisplay();
}
```

And it doesn't show the `ProgressDialog` so it didn't work the way I want. Since I belived it is because ProgressDialog is continues progress, it should be handled by another `Thread`.

**Here is my second attempt :**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Thread t = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(RSSReader.this, "Loading...", "Loading, please wait");
            feed = getFeed(RSSFEEDOFCHOICE);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }   
    };

    UpdateDisplay();
}
```

It was okay till `UpdateDisplay()` since this method was handled by main thread and it wasn't waiting anything so I thought maybe I should have put it under `t` Thread after `dialog.dismiss()`.

**So I did this :**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Thread t = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(RSSReader.this, "Loading...", "Loading, please wait");
            feed = getFeed(RSSFEEDOFCHOICE);
            dialog.dismiss();
                    UpdateDisplay();
        }   
    };
}
```

But then debugger said at run-time : *only the main thread which handles `onCreate():void` can reach and use View objects because it creates them.*

Now, I am so messed up and feel like quitting programming.

Some one can help me :/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,I've found the solution from your answers since your answers are not completely working

First we need to use `Handler` to post a Runnable to main/UI thread to run `UpdateDisplay()` and but define `ProgressDialog` under `UIThread` not other threads which was also crucial.

**Here is the final code :**

```
public final String RSSFEEDOFCHOICE = "http://www.deals2buy.com/rssgen/tech.xml";
public final String tag = "RSSReader";
private RSSFeed feed = null;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private ProgressDialog dialog;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(RSSReader.this, "Loading",
            "Loading, please wait..");
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            feed = getFeed(RSSFEEDOFCHOICE);
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    UpdateDisplay();
                };
            });
        }
    };

    t.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use AsyncTask, thats exactly what its for. Since onPostExecute(Long result) is done on the UI thread, it wont crash when looking for View objects.

Here is a example taken from [the asyncTask reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

What you want to do is obtain the RSS feed in doInBackground(), and then update the UI in onPostExecute.

In your onCreate() method, invoke the asyncTask.

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

Comment: Isn't there any other simple solution than that? I will check it. Thanks.

Comment: This is really simple, its the best solution for this problem. Google made AsyncTask specifically for cases like these.

Comment: Thanls, I will use it then :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your request in another thread than the progressdialog. So try with

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(icicle);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(RSSReader.this, "Loading...", "Loading, please wait");
Thread t = new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
        feed = getFeed(RSSFEEDOFCHOICE);
        dialog.dismiss();
        UpdateDisplay();
    }   
};
}
```

And depending on what you do in update display you should run it in the UI thread.

Comment: I've tried it but the problem was when code hits `UpdateDisplay`, it throws the error I mentioned at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the best way would be to use `AsyncTask`.

However as a quick workaround you could do smth like this:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Thread t = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(RSSReader.this, "Loading...", "Loading, please wait");
            feed = getFeed(RSSFEEDOFCHOICE);
            dialog.dismiss();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    UpdateDisplay();
                }
            });
        }   
    };
```

}

Comment: There is a run-time exception occurred : `ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1422): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`