# Displaying a custom AlertDialog in Android while catching an Exception

Tags: android, exception, dialog, alert, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to display an alert message for the users in a catch block. The difference is that my try/catch is inside the `onCreate()` from the main activity, so it's executed as soon as the application is opened.

I've tried this (I have an `OnClick()` for Dialogs in the end of the Activity with `dialog.dismiss()` and `this.finish()` after):

```
 catch (SQLException e) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(getString(R.string.label_title_error))
        .setIcon(R.drawable.error_icon)
        .setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_error_sql))
        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.label_ok), this);

        AlertDialog dialogSQL = builder.create();
        dialogSQL.show();

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and I also tried this:

```
   catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.label_title_error));
        dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.error_icon);
        dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_error_numberformat));
        dialog.setNeutralButton(getString(R.string.label_ok), null);

        dialog.create().show();

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Forced the exceptions while debugging and I can see that it simply catches the exception, displays in the LogCat (as warning) and keep with the flow until it hits another untreated exception and then display that default "Sorry!/Force Close" Android dialog. And there are no other exceptions related to the dialog in the LogCat.

Why it does not display my custom AlertDialogs for the catch? I thought about the context that the Builder needs, but if the `super()` from `onCreate()` is before this code so why it does displays the message?

Thanks Everyone.

UPDATE: Ok, as requested, here goes more code.

```
public class PinActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener{

private Facade facade = null;

public static int INSERT_SAL = 0;
public static int INSERT_OK = 1;
public static int INSERT_CANCEL = 2;

EditText edtIniPin;
TextView txtSelecPin;
TextView txtCancPin;

int pinMaxLengthInt;

private String[] serviceNames;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v("FLUXO", "PIN -->> ON CREATE");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    facade = Facade.getInstance();
    try {
        serviceNames = facade.loadApplication(this);
        facade.loadParameters(0);

        setContentView(R.layout.pin_screen);

        //Instanciando Views da Tela
        edtIniPin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPin);
        txtSelecPin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_select_pin);
        txtCancPin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel_pin);

        pinMaxLengthInt = Facade.getInstance().getPinSize();

        InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
        FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(pinMaxLengthInt);
        edtIniPin.setFilters(FilterArray);

        edtIniPin.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (edtIniPin.getText().length() > 0) {
                    txtCancPin.setText(getString(R.string.btn_clean));
                }
                else if (edtIniPin.getText().length() == 0){
                    txtCancPin.setText(getString(R.string.btn_exit));
                }
                else if (edtIniPin.getText().length() == Facade.getInstance().getPinSize()){
                    edtIniPin.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(getString(R.string.label_title_error))
        .setIcon(R.drawable.error_icon)
        .setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_error_sql))
        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.label_ok), this);

        AlertDialog dialogSQL = builder.create();
        dialogSQL.show();

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CorruptedAppException e) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(getString(R.string.label_title_error))
        .setIcon(R.drawable.error_icon)
        .setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_error_corrupted))
        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.label_ok), this);

        AlertDialog dialogCorrupted = builder.create();
        dialogCorrupted.show();

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoServiceAvailableException e) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(getString(R.string.label_title_error))
        .setIcon(R.drawable.error_icon)
        .setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_error_noservice))
        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.label_ok), this);

        AlertDialog dialogNoService = builder.create();
        dialogNoService.show();

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.label_title_error));
        dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.error_icon);
        dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_error_numberformat));
        dialog.setNeutralButton(getString(R.string.label_ok), null);

        dialog.create().show();

    e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.v("FLUXO", "PIN -->> ON ACTIVITY RESULT");
    if (resultCode == INSERT_OK) {
        String[] initCode = (String[]) data.getSerializableExtra("init_code");

        try {
            Facade.getInstance().insertInitCode(serviceNames[0], initCode, this);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(getString(R.string.label_title_error))
            .setIcon(R.drawable.error_icon)
            .setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_error_numberformat))
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.label_ok), this);

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(getString(R.string.label_title_error))
            .setIcon(R.drawable.error_icon)
            .setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_error_sql))
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.label_ok), this);

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (CorruptedAppException e) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(getString(R.string.label_title_error))
            .setIcon(R.drawable.error_icon)
            .setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_error_corrupted))
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.label_ok), this);

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if (resultCode == INSERT_CANCEL){
        this.finish();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    Log.v("FLUXO", "PIN -->> ON START");
    super.onStart();
    txtSelecPin.setOnClickListener(this);
    txtCancPin.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.v("FLUXO", "PIN -->> ON RESUME");
    super.onResume();

    if (!facade.isInitialized(serviceNames[0], this)) {
        Intent itInicial = new Intent(this, InitialActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(itInicial, INSERT_SAL);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Log.v("FLUXO", "PIN -->> ON STOP");
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Log.v("FLUXO", "PIN -->> ON PAUSE");
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.v("FLUXO", "PIN -->> ON BACK KEY PRESSED");
    super.onBackPressed();
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.v("FLUXO", "PIN -->> ON DESTROY");
    super.onDestroy();
}

/**
 * Método chama próxima tela
 */
private void nextScreen(){
    Log.v("FLUXO", "PIN -->> NEXT SCREEN");
    Intent it = new Intent(this, ValueActivity.class);
    startActivity(it);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
       //lots of stuff (...)
}

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    dialog.dismiss();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

}

Comment: COuld you show a bit more code? Especially the onCreate() method would be interesting. Also this stuff about calling dismiss on the dialogs at some point in the code is interesting. Might it be that you dismiss the dialog shortly after you opened it through the activity lifecycle calls?

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371842/progressdialog-problem-during-activiy-oncreatevoid-in-android

Comment: can you be more specific about adding a handler to display an alertdialog?

Comment: Use runOnUiThread() method if you are catching the error in async or backgroundtask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the life cicle of the Activity!

Heres what I did:

```
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        showDialog(
                R.string.label_title_error, 
                R.drawable.error_icon, 
                R.string.msg_error_noservice, 
                R.string.label_ok);
        error = true;
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

and this:

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.v("FLUXO", "PIN -->> ON RESUME");
    super.onResume();
    if (!error) {
        if (!facade.isInitialized(serviceNames[0], this)) {
            Intent itInicial = new Intent(this, InitialActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(itInicial, INSERT_SAL);
        }       

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`AlertDialog` generally needs its parent Context to be visible to work correctly (in my experience; someone correct me if I'm wrong). Barring other errors (hard to tell without the full code) you could probably make that work right if you move it into your `onResume()` function.

Comment: I've tryed to move to onResume but it didn't work the same way :(

Comment: It didn't work the same way? You mean it didn't display the dialog, or it didn't force close, or what specifically?

Comment: It didn't displayed the dialog, and then displayed the force close because of a nullpointer just after (facade.getInstance().isInitialized()...) the catch block (the nullpointer happened because of the exception).

Comment: It really looks like it should work: if you comment out the code that causes the second exception does the dialog show up then? It might just be a timing detail.

Comment: I've moving the code around the onCreate and onResume comenting some parts of it but it still didn't work :/

Comment: Quite odd: if you can attach the logcat output for when the crash happens, that might shed some light.