# Open AlertDialog after a crash

Tags: android, exception, android-alertdialog, crash-reports

I made an abstract fragment that other fragments extend with the following:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler oldHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();

    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread paramThread, Throwable paramThrowable) {
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(writer);
            paramThrowable.printStackTrace(printWriter);
            String s = writer.toString();
            Utils.logToFile(s);
            emailReport(s); ///<<<<<

            if (oldHandler != null) oldHandler.uncaughtException(paramThread, paramThrowable); //Delegates to Android's error handling
            else System.exit(2); //Prevents the service/app from freezing
        }
    });

}
```

Just before handing the process back to the OS (after storing the exception in a file) I call `emailReport(s);`

```
private void emailReport(final String report) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(getString(R.string.crash_report))
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.send_crash_report))
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        intent.setType("message/rfc822");
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Crash Report");
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, report);
                        Intent mailer = Intent.createChooser(intent, null);
                        startActivity(mailer);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();
    }
```

I want the alert dialog to show before the OS takes control so the user can either open his email client to send me the crash or cancel and close the app. The debug stops on the line that creates the alert dialog but after that, it jumps to the end of this method and from there, back to the old handler.

It could be another exception but I don't know that for sure and I can't catch it because I'm already in the middle of processing the current exception. Is there something wrong in the code? if not, how can I see what happens when trying to create the alert dialog?

UPDATE: I put the handling lines inside the setNegativeButton of the dialog, thinking it was shown but immediately closed but it didn't help:

```
        if (oldHandler != null) oldHandler.uncaughtException(paramThread, paramThrowable); //Delegates to Android's error handling
        else System.exit(2); //Prevents the service/app from freezing
    }
```

Comment: Did you try the use of try-catch phrases ?

Comment: You had a point there. Did it now, it doesn't have any exception so it just skips it without actually doing it, maybe because it is out of context at that point of the crash?

Comment: If an exception occurs, the app won't crash, but goes into the catch-clause. So in that catch-clause you could call your emailReport- method. Shall I give you an example ?

Comment: I made this abstract fragment in order to catch an exception globally. I don't want to try catch all my code :) The only question is how to handle this alert dialog and why it isn't created

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5915344/2245646

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you call imediatly the default handler which internally calls exit so your dialog is never been shown. So you method should look like this:

```
private void emailReport(final String report,
                         final Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler oldHandler) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle(getString(R.string.crash_report))
            .setMessage(getString(R.string.send_crash_report))
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:support@example.com"));
                    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Crash Report");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, report);
                    Intent mailer = Intent.createChooser(intent, null);
                    startActivity(mailer);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    if(oldHandler != null) {
                        //Delegates to Android's error handling
                        oldHandler.uncaughtException(paramThread, paramThrowable);
                    } else {
                         // Force to close the app now after handling the crash bug
                         System.exit(2);
                    }
                }
            })
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .show();
}
```

And don't miss to remove the last two lines:

```
if (oldHandler != null) oldHandler.uncaughtException(paramThread, paramThrowable); //Delegates to Android's error handling
else System.exit(2); //Prevents the service/app from freezing
```

Comment: I prefer not to use 3rd party components and rely on them. If I can do something on my own (I need a very simple mechanism), I prefer to go this way.

Comment: I just say how they do it. You should just try the idea, I did not say that you should use ACRA.

Comment: So instead of using the activity that might not be there at this point, making a new one and use it... will give it a try

Comment: The MainActivity is still alive so it doens't explain it, I updated my question above. I put the handler lines inside the setNegativeButton and explained why, but it didn't help.

Comment: Okay I missed that part a little. The default handler calles exit too. So you should call the orginal handler also only in the negative button handling. If that helps I'll rewrite my answer.

Comment: Already did that and updated my question above - didn't help :)

Comment: That's what I did, I just see a blank window and nothing happens. Also, the debug disconnects as if the app is no longer there

Comment: I improved your mail intent by the way that should look now nicer. That should work if you don't call the `oldHandler` nor `System.exit()`. Check that twice that you don't call that.

Comment: I removed those lines from the main method and moved it to the negativeButton - no help. I now tried this: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/03/13/customize-force-close-dialog-android/ but the uncaughtException method never called, even on exception